# Javascript: Solve a system of equations

Tags: javascript, math, solver

I'm making a dew point calculator using the "[closer approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point)" on wikipedia.

I want to be able to calculate the dew point if the user enters any two variables.

Is there an easy way to do this rather than having a lot of if-statements?

More specifically: What if I wanted to use the wet-bulb temperature instead of the relative humidity? Would I have to make a new function or use an if-statement to exclude a set of variables?

Currently I'm using the temperature and relative humidity:

```
    $('#calculate').click(function(){
        //Get Temp
        var T = parseInt($('#val1').val());
        //Get RH
        var RH = parseInt($('#val2').val());
        //Get es and ex
        var es = 6.112*Math.exp(17.76*T/(T+243.5));
        var ex = (RH*es)/100;
        //Calculate Dew Point
        var Tdp = (243.5*Math.log(ex/6.112))/(17.67-Math.log(ex/6.112));
        $('#output').append("<p>Dew Point"+Tdp+"</p>");

    });
```

Comment: Using only two variables right now. I'm not sure if it's possible to solve a system of equations in javascript, so I'm sticking with the most common inputs. :)

Comment: +1 for interesting question. However, I'm pretty sure it's going to come down to `if`'s or a `switch() case;` statement.

Comment: @KevinBrown: Ok that is much better :) (BTW I have no idea about how to answer your question), just thought it could be more complete.

Comment: BTW I would remove my vote to close if I could. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe you could start writing a javascript library for that and share the code with the community :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI solving systems of nonlinear equations is generally a hard problem.  Do whatever you can to avoid that.

My usual approach if multiple pairs of values can be used to calculate an answer is to use the pair of values I'm given to calculate a canonical pair of values, which then is used to do the real calculation.  Furthermore since it gets messy to have to sort through input to figure out what you have been given so you can DWIM, it might make sense to have separate functions for each pair of inputs that I'll accept.  (Or it might not depending on the flow of control in your program, you know that better than I do.)

Comment: I literally just picked this up on a whim--no job this summer, so I'm fooling around. :)
Any advice is welcomed. :)

Comment: That's a tool I always wanted. Something where you type in mathematical relationships in one section, and then type in the values you DO know in a grid and it automatically fills in what it can. This may require the likes of Maxima running behind the scenes.

Comment: But there are some computer algebra systems in JavaScript (such as [Nerdamer](http://www.nerdamer.com/demo.html?eq=solveEquations(%5Bx%5E2=y+1,%20y%5E2=2%5D))) that can solve systems of nonlinear equations.